# While extracting text I got AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm running the following code in order to scrape the price from the page, but I keep getting this error. Initially I tried just adding the inner class to attrs{} and then I tried including the class that it was within but both times I got the same error.
I don't think there's a problem with the url because when I ran `webbrowser.open(url)` it worked. Also, `print(soup.prettify())` did give me the contents of the page so I doubt there's a problem there. What should I do?

```
def getCurrentPrice(cc): #Scraping the current price of the cryptocurrency from the web

    url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+cc+'+price+euros'
    #webbrowser.open(url)

    HTML=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(HTML.text, 'html.parser')

    #print(soup.prettify())

    text=soup.find('div', attrs= {'class': 'card-section PZPZlf'}).find('div', attrs={'class': 'pclqee'}).text
    print('Current Price: '+text+'EUR')

    return text
```

```
line 47, in getCurrentPrice
text=soup.find('div', attrs= {'class': 'card-section PZPZlf'}).find('div', attrs={'class': 'pclqee'}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: `find()` can return `None`. You have to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

I think because `soup.find()` can return None

Fix:

```py
def getCurrentPrice(cc): #Scraping the current price of the cryptocurrency from the web
    """Function that get the current price. Can return None"""

    url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+cc+'+price+euros'
    #webbrowser.open(url)

    HTML=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(HTML.text, 'html.parser')

    #print(soup.prettify())

    text=soup.find('div', attrs= {'class': 'card-section PZPZlf'})
    
    if text is not None:
        text = text.find('div', attrs={'class': 'pclqee'})
    else:
        return
    if text is not None:
        text = text.text
    else:
        return

    print('Current Price: '+text+'EUR')

    return text
```

This function can return None.